# jdbc connector change data listener

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I want to implement chat between two users in mobile, I'm using android studio and store the messages in AWS(amazon) MySQL database.

I manage to read messages every time user starts the chat activity like so:

```
void onCreate() {
   readHistoryMessagesFromLocalDataBase();
   readMessagesFromGlobalDataBase();
}
```

The first function is used to read the history messages from the local database of Android using SQLite.

The second function is used to read any new messages waiting on the global database of Amazon using MySQL.

This works perfectly, but how can I receive messages in real time while I'm already in the activity without reloading or refreshing?

Is there any data change listener to achieve this goal?

Comment: Look into web sockets. The server establishes a persistent connection with the device and can send updates as they happen.

Comment: Can you explain more? :)

Comment: It's a somewhat complicated topic. There are plenty of resources on the web with good examples.